# deleting indiviual pointers from an array

Tags: c++, pointers

So, If if have an array of pointers

```
stuff **items;
stuff *testPTR;
items = new stuff[200];
```

the contents of which are used to hold dynamic memory objects

```
items[0] = new stuff;
items[1] = new stuff;
etc. 
testPTR = items[0];
```

and I want to delete the items, how come this doesn't work?

```
delete items[0];
delete items[1];
etc.
delete [] items;
```

I tested this code and I could still access things that where allocated using testPTR (after the delete statements ran) which i set earlier.

```
//stuff held in items[0] is still accessible with
*testPTR
```

I am confused becuase if I cout items[any position] I will get a memory address which delete should use to return the memory that was allocated for stuff, but the code above seems to leave the stuff and only delete the pointer array. What am I missing? 
Thank You
//edited to make question clearer

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<stuff>>` and then you don't have to delete anything any more.

Answer (score 4):

`delete items[0]` only deallocates memory that `items[0]` points to, it does NOT set items[0] to NULL. You have to do that yourself.

```
delete items[0];
items[0] = NULL;
etc
```

As other answers point out, the actual deallocation of the memory might not happen right away, but that's an implementation detail of the memory management system and you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: thank you, but I realize that. The strange thing that I am running into is that I can still access the data held in testPTR even after it should have been deleted by running delete items[0]

Comment: What Namfuak said :-)

Comment: Cross-recursion between answers ? Oh God, we're doo

Comment: ...and if we remove one of the answers, then we'll have a dangling pointer, thus demonstrating what happens when you `delete answers[0]` :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what pbkhrv said, `delete` has no obligation to immediately release the memory back to the operating system, so it is undefined behavior whether you can still access memory returned.  You will only get a segmentation fault if your program no longer owns the memory space you are trying to access, but if `delete` didn't actually give it back to the operating system the operating system still sees your program as owning the memory and doesn't mind that you are accessing it.  The reason `delete` may not give back the memory is simply that it is much faster to keep the memory allocated to your program and if you call `new` again, just give you a pointer to the same memory you already own.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, especially Namfuak one.

Take a look at the short program bellow:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) 
{
    char *p = new char [1];
    for (int i=0; 1;i++){
       p[i]=0;
       cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I guess you would expect that it will crash when i=1. but for me it actually can run till 32 or 64.

Obviously I didn't allocate all the memory I can access to. but still I can access to it.

So as you can see, when you ask for 1 byte you get you get allocation of more, because dynamic allocations are slow operations. it actually allocate a larger block for efficiency.

And you can use some addresses after freed since you didn't free the whole block.

Comment: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/0Fm7p5) doesn't segfault until 12774 and it does so because our `stdout` file is too long.  I'd assume its environment just allocates a bunch of memory in the virtual runtime before program execution.

Comment: It OS and compiler dependent, It just simplify the idea of allocations in blocks and the fact the whole block will free when you delete all the allocations from the block.